# How can I test using WAF to protect API Gateway RestAPI from SQL injection contained in request payload?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, sql-injection, amazon-waf

I've created a few resources in AWS in an attempt to create MRE showcasing how the WAF can be used to prevent malicious requests from being sent to an API Gateway RestAPI.
Ive created

- S3 Bucket
- Kinesis Data Firehose
- WAF Web ACL
- API Gateway RestAPI

Ive associated the RestAPI with the WAF ACL at the stage-level. The WAF Web ACL has been configured to use the an AWS managed rule
**AWS-AWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet**

> The SQL database rule group contains rules to block request patterns
> associated with exploitation of SQL databases, like SQL injection
> attacks. This can help prevent remote injection of unauthorized
> queries. Evaluate this rule group for use if your application
> interfaces with an SQL database.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/aws-managed-rule-groups-list.html

Configured with defaults shown below
[image]

This is the only rule and all other defaults were chosen, as shown below.
[image]

Ive created a serverless api POST resource endpoint and despite having everything configured as described above, requests with payload/body as shown below are not blocked by the WAF.
[image]

```
    {
 "MyString":"SELECT username, password FROM Users"
}
```

Why arent requests being blocked by the WAF? How can I configure so that requests with SQL within request payload are rejected at the WAF before being sent to RestAPI?

I assumed that my SQL above would be enough. Is that not true? What SQL code can I use to validate the WAF and AWS Managed Rule is working as expected? What logic could explain why my request above is not being blocked?

Ive also configured S3 logging, and here is an example of 1 of the records from the s3 log, showing that this request was allowed

```
    "timestamp": 1612921225458,
"formatVersion": 1,
"webaclId": "ABC",
"terminatingRuleId": "Default_Action",
"terminatingRuleType": "REGULAR",
"action": "ALLOW",
"terminatingRuleMatchDetails": [],
"httpSourceName": "APIGW",
"httpSourceId": "ABC:ABC:Prod",
"ruleGroupList": [{
        "ruleGroupId": "AWS#AWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet",
        "terminatingRule": null,
        "nonTerminatingMatchingRules": [],
        "excludedRules": null
    }
],
"rateBasedRuleList": [],
"nonTerminatingMatchingRules": [],
"requestHeadersInserted": null,
"responseCodeSent": null,
```

What assumption am I making that is incorrect here?

I would like an MRE that shows how WAF rejects the request when post body contains malicious looking SQL, and also return 4xx response. I'm assuming this is achievable.

Update 1: Ive tried to add my own rules and rule groups, using rule builder and specifically looking at the request body. Even with these in place, it still does not reject.
[image]

Ive added rules for Body, Query string, Path. Still, request was not rejected
[image]